# Struct data type when creating dataframe with createDataFrame in Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, struct

In PySpark, we can create *struct* data type when using `createDataFrame` like in the following example `("b", "c")` and `("e", "f")`

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ["a", ("b", "c")],
    ["d", ("e", "f")]
])

df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
df.show()
# +---+------+
# | _1|    _2|
# +---+------+
# |  a|{b, c}|
# |  d|{e, f}|
# +---+------+
```

Is there a similar way in Scala - to create struct schema inside `createDataFrame`, without using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your specific example, you can use tuples and call [this flavor](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SparkSession.html#createDataFrame%5BA%3C:Product%5D(data:Seq%5BA%5D)(implicitevidence$3:reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag%5BA%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) of `createDataFrame`.

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  ("a", ("b", "c")),
  ("d", ("e", "f"))
))

df.printSchema()
/*
root
 |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
*/

df.show()
/*
+---+------+
| _1|    _2|
+---+------+
|  a|[b, c]|
|  d|[e, f]|
+---+------+
*/
```

<sup>Instead of `("b", "c")` one can also use `"b" -> "c"` to create a tuple of length 2.</sup>

**Preferred method**

Tuples can become difficult to manage when dealing with many fields and especially nested fields. Likely, you'll want to model your data using `case class`(s). This also allows to specify struct field names and types.

```scala
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class Car(manufacturer: String, model: String, mileage: Double, owner: Person)

val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  Car("Toyota", "Camry", 81400.8, Person("John", 37)),
  Car("Honda", "Accord", 152090.2, Person("Jane", 25))
))

df.printSchema()
/*
root
 |-- manufacturer: string (nullable = true)
 |-- model: string (nullable = true)
 |-- mileage: double (nullable = false)
 |-- owner: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
*/

df.show()
/*
+------------+------+--------+----------+
|manufacturer| model| mileage|     owner|
+------------+------+--------+----------+
|      Toyota| Camry| 81400.8|[John, 37]|
|       Honda|Accord|152090.2|[Jane, 25]|
+------------+------+--------+----------+
*/
```

Comment: Thank you! Do I understand it correctly that `"b" -> "c"` notation can only be used to create 2 fields inside struct? So it can't be used to create 3 fields?

Comment: @ZygD the `->` operator is just syntax sugar for creating a [`Tuple2`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Tuple2.html) object. `0 -> 1`, `(0, 1)`, and `Tuple2(0, 1)` are all equivalent. This is a Scala language property, not Spark SQL. But if you would want to create a 3-tuple (tuple with three "fields"), you can simply use the parentheses method: `(0, 1, 2)`. Although, as mentioned in my original answer, the more fields you start to use wrt tuples, the more a case class makes more sense.